# Measure heap used by each object in Java

Tags: java, jmx

Can some suggest a good a free memory profiling tool which will show memory being used by each object in the heap separately. We are trying to profile our application and I used jconsole but its gives me total memory usage only. I am using Eclipse and OC4J

Comment: Agree with @BalusC, few people will answer a question from a user who never marks as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual VM can do it for you..

https://visualvm.java.net/

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

Answer (score 0):

Not free, but IMHO the best one: http://www.yourkit.com/