# Measure heap memory used by individual objects

Tags: jvm

Just curious, Is there a way to measure the heap memory consumed by each individual object from **inside the code** in realtime?

(I know I can use VisualVM and Eclipse Memory Analyzer as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553680/measure-heap-used-by-each-object-in-java), but is there a way to do this from the inside?)

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way if there are already decent tools?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to you the free tools available, you can look into the Hprof (freely available)code, try to change it in your own way. Hprof internally uses JVMTI . It will work.